# Excluir barras en preg_match en php

Tags: php, laravel, regex

Estoy haciendo una validación personalizada de cuentas de Instagram.

Es simple, si la respuesta de instagram es un error `404` significa que el usuario no existe. Sin embargo, al introducir por ejemplo en mi campo `"direct/inbox/"` claramente mi validación da un `"verdadero"` como estado debido a que esa es una URL válida dentro de mi regla ya que es el centro de mensajes de Instagram

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $instagramResponse = Http::get('https://instagram.com/' . $value)->status();
    return preg_match('/^\S*$/u', $value) && $instagramResponse != 404;
}
```

Así que estoy intentando limitar lo que es el slash `"/"` en mi validación de Instagram para que el usuario **no pueda introducir** eso o similares, simplemente nombres de usuario.

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
preg_match('/^\S*$/u', $value)
```

Que no deja introducir espacios pero quiero añadir a la regla la prohibición de barras `/`.

¿Cómo lo puedo añadir?

Comment: te recomiendo implementar el api de instagram; ellos tiene una opción en donde puedes identificar si el nombre de usuarios es correcto: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api#legacy-ids o https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: ¿Necesitas validar caracteres alfa-numéricos y algún otro caracter especial como `-` o `_`?

Comment: @Marcos no es necesario, las cuentas pueden llevar dichos caracteres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\S` es lo mismo que `[^\s]` (un caracter que no es un espacio en blanco).

Aprovechando la [clase de caracteres negada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.character-classes.php), se puede agregar cualquier otro caracter que quieras excluir: `[^\s\/]`

```
preg_match( '/^[^\s\/]+$/', $value)
```

Además, te conviene ver que se cumpla esta condición ***antes*** de disparar la consulta HTTP, que puede demorar en devolver el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas validar caracteres alfanuméricos (*del `0` al `9` y de la `a` a la `z`*), entonces podes hacerlo así:

```php
<?php

$regEx = '/^[0-9a-z]+$/i';
$value = 'direct/';
echo preg_match($regEx, $value);
```